# checkbox checking all siblings of nested checkbox inside a td

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, laravel-5.4

please help me how to:
check all the siblings if the checkbox parent is check, and also if some child/children of a checkbox was checked, then the parent also must be checked. How can i do this?

i have this in my laravel code:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="tableOrders">                                    
    <thead class="thead-inverse">                        
        <tr>
          <th width="4%"><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" /></th>
          <th width="7%">USER ID</th>
          <th width="12%">AMOUNT</th>
          <th width="15%">SHIP DATE</th>
          <th width="15%">RECEIVER</th>
          <th width="20%">ADDRESS</th>
          <th width="14%">MOBILE #</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>                        
    <tbody>
         <?php $i=0 ?>                             
         @foreach($shippings as $data)                             
        <tr>

            <td><input type="checkbox" class="parent" name="shippings[][]" value="{{ $data->shipping_id }}" />&nbsp;</td>                                
            <td><a href="#" data-value="{{ $data->user_id }}" class="linkedit"> {{ $data->user_id }} </a></td>
            <td><a href="#" data-value="{{ $data->total_amount }}" class="linkedit"> {{ $data->total_amount }} </a></td>
            <td><a href="#" data-value="{{ $data->shipping_date }}" class="linkedit"> {{ $data->shipping_date }} </a></td>
            <td><a href="#" data-value="{{ $data->shipping_receiver }}" class="linkedit"> {{ $data->shipping_receiver }} </a></td>
            <td><a href="#" data-value="{{ $data->shipping_address }}" class="linkedit"> {{ $data->shipping_address }} </a></td>   
            <td><a href="#" data-value="{{ $data->mobile_number }}" class="linkedit"> {{ $data->mobile_number }} </a></td>                                
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><p style="font-weight:bold;">Product Name</p></td>
            <td><p style="font-weight:bold;">Price</p></td>
            <td><p style="font-weight:bold;">Ordered Qty</p></td>
            <td><p style="color:red;font-weight: bold;">Available Qty</p></td>
        </tr>                              
          @foreach($data->products as $product)

                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" class="child" name="shippings[{{$i}}][products][]" value="{{ $product->product_id }}" />&nbsp;</td>                
                  <td>{{ $product->product_name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $product->price }}</td>                              
                  <td>{{ $product->quantity }}</td>
                  <td><p style="color:red;"> {{ $product->available_qty }}</p></td>                                      
                </tr>                              
          @endforeach                        
          <?php $i++; ?>                            
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have my jsfiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/jKxNF/112/

I am very confused because i did it in my laravel loop, but the structure of it is in the jsfiddle.

Comment: how can you say it is siblings? per row or per td?

Comment: @guradio per td. thanks for reply

Comment: so when sample1 is check sample2 and sample3 should be checked?

Comment: @guradio sorry, i updated my jsfiddle link.. please check

Comment: what is parent in this case,, john, jacob?

Comment: @KresimirPendic yes sir, sorry i updated my jsfiddle please take a look. thanks

Comment: i suggest get the index of the checked checkbox and use to to check/uncheck same index for the rest of the rows

Comment: @guradio are you referring like this? name="shippings[][]"

Comment: @JcJohn - See if this raw example works for you >> http://jsfiddle.net/jKxNF/114/

Comment: @guradio how can i do something like this, because my checkboxes are made dynamic: for example i have my first checkbox, i put something name checkbox1 and it has three siblings. sample 1, sample2, sample 3. if i check the checkbox1 the siblings are also checked and if i check some siblings of it, then the parent is checked

Comment: @Kyra it only displays when i checked. is that what you mean?

Comment: @JcJohn - That only shows a way to select the adjacent table cells and find the values you need. Might have to adjust to your needs.

Comment: @Kyra i want to get the siblings not the checked, please checked my updated jsfiddle

Comment: @JcJohn - Is this what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/jKxNF/115/ Please see the changes to the markup.

Comment: @Kyra hello, please let me have one question, can i make a data-target ="1" ? and make td class="1"?

Comment: @JcJohn I would use some value from your data, such as `{{ $data->user_id }}`, possibly hashed to prevent disclosing the real value.

Comment: @Kyra i will do like this data-target = "{{ $data->shipping_id }}". can i make a <td class="{{ $data->shipping_id }}"> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add an attribute to the triggering checkboxes such as

```
<input type="checkbox"  data-target=".prefix-{{ $data->shipping_id }}">
```

and using a class on the targeted `<td>`

```
<td class="prefix-{{ $data->shipping_id }}"><input type="checkbox">Sample3</td>
```

The following Javascript will select the relevant checkboxes

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e) {
    var checked = $(this).prop('checked')
    var target = $(this).data('target')

    if(checked){
        $(target).find('input').prop('checked', true)
    } else {
        $(target).find('input').prop('checked', false)
    }
});
```

The data attribute value should be a selector, either `#prefix-{{ $data->shipping_id }}` if you use an ID or `.prefix-{{ $data->shipping_id }}` if you use a class

Comment: i will do like this data-target = "{{ $data->shipping_id }}". can i make a <td class="{{ $data->shipping_id }}"> ?